# Pre controller event Gesdinet

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony and trying to find a way to get the request prior to `gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle`. In previous versions there was a controller event `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` which one could use. But now the only info I get is `gesdinet refresh symfony: controller action is deprecated` and find no way to get the request prior to refreshing the token.

Would appreciate help finding the right event or way to get the request and modify it a bit before it reaches the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to be simple. By adding custom refresh token extractor

```
namespace App\Request\Extractor;

use Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundle\Request\Extractor\ExtractorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

final class HeaderExtractor implements ExtractorInterface
{
    public function getRefreshToken(Request $request, string $parameter): ?string
    {
        return $request->headers->get('X-Refresh-Token');
    }
}
```

And adding it to services.yaml

```
services:
    App\Request\Extractor\HeaderExtractor:
        tags:
            - { name: gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.request_extractor }
```